# How do I give a player a colored leather armor using commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to assign players a color in a Spleef game by giving them colored leather armor, although I could not find any tutorials on how that would work on Pocket Edition.

My syntax:

```
replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head 0 leather_armor 1 0 {“display”:{“color”:16777215”}}
```

It says that “display” is not a supported component. Also “16777215” in “color” is the decimal value of white, therefore giving my leather helmet a white color. Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that currently it is impossible to do this. This is since bedrock doesn't support nbt data, as stated in the Reddit link below:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/f723ga/bedrock_edition_give_and_equip_dyed_leather_armor/

However, there is a sneaky work around I am making up on the fly (so comment if there is something I can fix):
The idea is you can tp said player under a dispenser which fires, dispensing the armor piece. If you are required to keep the player in the same spot before the tp (instead of moving them to a start area), you can use an entity to save the position:

```
/tp @e[name="tpPos"] <player>
/tp <player> x y z
*power dispenser*
/tp <player> @e[name="tpPos"]
```

To fill the dropper up again, you can clone a different one with the item in it:

```
/clone x1 y1 z1 x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z1
```

(coordinate set 1 is the saved dispenser, coordinate set 2 is the dispenser to refill)

---

I just noticed @SomeguySomewere beat me to this answer :)
I hope the commands help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in Bedrock Edition
since this is NBT data and Bedrock doesn't seem to support that. You could try auto equipping it using droppers?
You could tp the player to an area were droppers fire and then tp him to the arena
(Tip use /clone to refill the dispensers)

Hope this helps and good luck on your spleef map!