# Unable name an item with /give command Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know this has been asked but I an unable to name an item with /give on Bedrock Edition.

The command below is what I have been trying:

```
/give @s minecraft:stone 1 0 {display:{Name:"Test"}}
```

And this is what it keeps saying:
[image: Error Message]

I have also tried:

```
/give @s stone 1 0 {display:{Name:"Test"}}
```

But it says this instead:

[image: Error Message 2]

Comment: There is no access to NBT from commands in Bedrock Edition. [View the most popular workaround.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374643/250180)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties)