# what does "line 1 column 2, missing "}" or object member mean?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried `/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:["minecraft:knockback"{id:lvl,1000}` and it gave me that upsetting error. does this command not work on xbox? am I doing it wrong?

Comment: what version are you on?

Comment: This is due to the fact that NBT is inaccessible from commands. The commands you found work on Java Edition only, not on Xbox. See the following post for info on what other things you could do instead: [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties)

Comment: The aforementioned reason isn't the reason it is giving you that error, You never closed the `[` or second `{`. You only closed the first curly brace. However, even if you fixed it it would still not work for the reason given before.

Comment: Thanks guys  for the help! I really need to get Java edition though. All I do in Minecraft is waste my time doing Java commands. But thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

your command is malformed, and has two open brackets at the end.
this wouldn't work anyway, though, NBT doesn't work on any non-java versions.