# How do i give players already enchanted Tools

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im making a spleef mini-game map, and i want to give players already enchanted Shovels.

I managed to find how to put restrictions on the shovels so they just break Snow, but I couldn't find how to put efficiency enchantments together

`/give @p diamond_shovel 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["snow"]}}`

> How do i modify this to enchant the shovels?

Comment: We've got a solution for that: [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (that I know of) to give enchanted tools with commands on bedrock edition.

However, you can use `/enchant @p efficiency 10` right after you give to enchant.

Comment: Hey, I'm afraid that there actually is a way to do this. Have you seen our [collection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180) of MCBE NBT workarounds?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 well he isn't really wrong, in that method you aren't actually directly giving it to the player, it still exists as an entity which isn't as nice as just directly giving it to them