# Does anyone know how to use the /give command for enchanted tools or armor on Pocket Edition 1.19?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm not quite sure how to use this command to give, for example, a knockback 20 stick. Could I have some help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties)

Answer (score -1):

For the Pocket Edition the fastest way is to first give yourself a stick and afterwards hold it and enchant it.

```
/give @s stick
/enchant @s knockback 2
```

The maximum knockback level is 2 I think.

Comment: You can't put knock back on a stick in bedrock without mods.